# Excel Find/Regex in C# ignore newlines

Tags: c#, excel

I have a C# program that uses the Excel API. One of the things i do with it is scan a range (r) for a cell that matches a string (s).

```
Func<Excel.Range, string, Excel.Range> ExcelSearch = (r, s) => r.Find(s, Type.Missing, 
      Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart, 
      Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, 
      false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

This works great for the most part except if I have a column where someone put a newline in the middle.  Example, trying to find "My Column", I'd like to match a cell if it has "My\nColumn".  Poking around I don't see anything in the API that supports regex.

I'm tempted to temporarily change all the cells I'm trying to search to remove all newlines first, but that seems like a bit of a brute force method to solve this problem.